How to push the same changes (diff) to multiple remotes with diverging history?
I have two upstream repositories ftp05 and ftp06 that contain diverging git history. However, some files are shared between them. Now I made changes to a file which is the same for both repositories and I want to push those changes upstream to both remotes. How can I do this in the most efficient way?
The way I have done it so far is like so:

git checkout ftp05/master
git checkout -b newbranch
(add changes and commit)
git push --force-with-lease (+ create upstream branch)
git checkout ftp06/master
git checkout -b newbranch-ftp06
git cherry-pick (earlier commit)
git push --force-with-lease (+ create upstream branch in ftp06)

As you can see there seem to be quite some redundant steps for this task. How can I do this more optimally?
in both repositories. How can I push only the changes made to this file to the upstream repository without dragging the whole diverging history from remote "origin" to

That's the way to do it, actually.... consider creating an alias or a script that could take care of the different steps with only a few parameters.


there seem to be quite some redundant steps for this task

No, not really. The only unnecessary step is that you are checking out the remote-tracking branch before starting a new branch at that point; instead of
git checkout ftp05/master
git checkout -b newbranch

you should say
git switch -c newbranch ftp05/master

But otherwise there's nothing "redundant" or "inefficient" about what you're doing; given the circumstances, what you're doing is the simplest and clearest approach.
